# Sum of Variance and mean for a set of data?

Tags: statistics

The question is as follows,

Group A contains 20 students and has a mean of 66 and variance of 9.
Group B contains 30 students and has a mean of 51 and variance of 31.

Find the mean and variance of all the 50 students.

Would anyone please be able to help out? I can deal with the mean but need a hand with variance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be your quality concerning each individual student, and $I$ be an indicator random variable where 
$$I = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{student is in group A} \\
1, & \text{student is in group B.} 
\end{cases}$$
Now 
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[X \mid I]\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X \mid I = 0]\mathbb{P}(I = 0) + \mathbb{E}[X \mid I = 1]\mathbb{P}(I = 1) \\
&= 66(20/50) + 51(30/50) \\
&= 57\text{.}
\end{align}$$
For the variance, we have
$$\begin{align}
\text{Var}[X] = \mathbb{E}\left[\text{Var}[X \mid I]\right] + \text{Var}\left[\mathbb{E}[X \mid I]\right]\text{.}
\end{align}$$
By the [Bernoulli Shortcut](https://tkchen.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/the-bernoulli-shortcut/), we have $$\text{Var}\left[\mathbb{E}[X \mid I]\right] = (66-51)^{2}\left(\dfrac{20}{50}\right)\left(\dfrac{30}{50}\right) = 54\text{.}$$
Now $$\begin{align}
\text{Var}[X \mid I = 0] &= 9 \\
\text{Var}[X \mid I = 1] &= 31 \\ 
\end{align}$$
so that $$\mathbb{E}\left[\text{Var}[X \mid I]\right] = 9\left(\dfrac{20}{50}\right) + 31\left(\dfrac{30}{50}\right) = 22.2$$
and $\text{Var}[X] = 54 + 22.2 = 76.2$.